# Is there a way to open another terminal with access to the same program I'm running to pass more formal parameters to it?

Tags: c, sdl

I'm making a program to learn SDL right now, and I have a switch statement in my main function that I'm using to open an SDL window. I also want to be able to use this switch statement to exit the program safely by passing another argument through the command line. Is this actually possible? If not what are some common solutions around this? I could always just bind a key press event to exit it but I wanted to allow the user to make adjustments to the program through the terminal as its running.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 int opt; 
 while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "iq")) != -1)
  {
    switch (opt)
     {
      case 'i':
       init_window();
       break;
      case 'q':
       quit_safely();
       break;
     }
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some information from someone that said the following.

"No. Command line arguments are set in stone once the program executes, if you need to signal the process in some way you need a method of IPC. A process signal is one option in the case."

A signal handler COULD do the trick, but what I've realized is that SDL has a bunch of functions that already make use of signal handlers in order to exit the program safely. I've made a function that uses these and will just use event handlers to call it instead.

Comment: A signal handler is different from an event handler.  A signal will only cause the program to do something - it doesn't have any parameters.

Comment: @cup Sorry I'll explain better, SDL has built in functions to destroy the program and exit safely. These functions already make use of signal handlers. The function I made has SDL's shutdown functions inside it. I'm just using event handlers to call the function that I made.